# array_filter on deep multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as such:

```
$d = [
    0 => [
        0 => 'lorem',
        1 => 'dorem',
        3 => '',
        4 => 'ipsum'
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => 'test',
        1 => 'rere',
        3 => '',
        4 => 'youp'
    ]
];
```

My issue is that I need to remove empty values from the array. How would I go about using `array_filter` in removing such empty keys/values from the multidimensional array? I have over 162 sets of arrays totaling 62 each, so this problem is via a large data set.

Comment: 2 levels only? Try `array_map('array_filter', $d)`. For more nested levels you can use pointers or recursive functions.

Comment: you are a genius. please post as answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2D arrays this method will work: `array_map('array_filter', $d);`

For more nested levels you can use pointers or recursive functions:

```
$result = clean($d);

function clean($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $index => $item)
    {
        if (is_array($item))
        {
            $array[$index] = clean($item);
        }

        if (!$array[$index])
        {
            unset($array[$index]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: thoughts on how to reformat array keys in numerical order after such changes to the array?

Comment: @Zach Smith, for 2D array: `array_map('array_values', $d);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` like this, [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef669df033a36e205e918702d75bae8d97d472ee)

```
foreach($d as &$array){
    $array = array_filter($array);
}
var_dump($d);
```